# Find the middle of a weighted list

Tags: python

How to find the index `i` that minimizes `abs(sum(A[:i])-sum(A[i:]))`.

Examples:

```
ex1: A = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], i = 3
ex2: A = [1, 2, 3], i = 2
ex3: A = [9, 1, 2, 3, 4], i = 1
ex4: A = [1, 2, 3, 4], i = 3
```

Comment: Iterate over all indices, compute the cost function and output the index with the least cost?

Answer (score 2):

Let us denote by S<sub>i</sub> the value abs(sum(A[:i])-sum(A[i:])). If you knew all the values you could find the minimum, right? Do a simple iteration and find this value.

Now the problem is how to compute the values S<sub>i</sub>. As it turns out this is not very hard: first compute the sum of all elements SUM. Then iterate from left to right and accumulate the sum of all elements to the left of the current position(denote that left<sub>i</sub>). S<sub>i</sub> = abs((SUM - left<sub>i</sub>) - left<sub>i</sub>).

So what you need to do is two iterations over the input - one to compute the total sum and second to find the value S<sub>i</sub> (and find the minimum of them).

Comment: `numpy.cumsum` might come in handy here

Comment: For future readers: `numpy.cumsum` would essentially compute the sums I suggest in the second iteration. (left<sub>i</sub>) Also obviously SUM = left<sub>N</sub>. You'll still need a second iteration to find the element minimizing the absolute difference, but the code will be shorter and cleaner